# uiAutomator failing on 4.1.2 device

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

When playing with the Android uiAutomator I've run into an issue when trying to run the tests on a 4.1.2 device.
When using the code from the [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) an exception is thrown when attempting to scroll the apps tray.

I originally thought it was caused by compiling against api 17 rather than 16 but that doesn't seem to be true.
Anyone else encountered this?

Exception raised:

> [exec] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   [exec]     at com.example.runTests(Runner.java:124)
>   [exec]     at com.example.testExecutor(Runner.java:60)
>   [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
>   [exec]     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
>   [exec]     at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:124)
>   [exec]     at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:85)
>   [exec]     at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:76)
>   [exec]     at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
>   [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>   [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
>   [exec]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   [exec] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.setAsHorizontalList
>   [exec]     at com.example.Runner.launchAppFromHomeScreen(Test.java:45)
>   [exec]     ... 19 more

Answer (score 7):

UIAutomator's codes has changes:

```
4.1.1 method : public void setAsHorizontalList ()
4.2 method : public UIScrollable setAsHorizontalList ()
```

It's maybe you are using API-17's UIAutomator to build the tests
but running on a API-16 device.
Try using the corresponding UIAutomator.jar

Comment: It's weird, I've solved this by using the right UIAutomator.jar.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  My target was android-16 and my device was 4.2.2.  After changing target to android-17 it worked fine.

Comment: @MrChaz Did you do a ant clean before trying again? That got me.

Comment: I tried cleaning and building but still found this error. I found that my project.properties still had the target set to 17 whilst the phone I was deploying to was target 16. After changing the project.properties to 16 everything worked.

Comment: @Aria4Larry  Wow...Where did you find the different code changes based on API version.  Is UiAutomator open source?

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments this week with UI Automator it's still seems immature, with the best support available with android-17 as your target and with a device running 4.2.1. I tried using my Galaxy S device which has 4.1.2 installed and had similar errors to those you report.

FYI: I think there's a bug in Android 4.2.2 that stops scrollIntoView(...) calls from swiping more than once. I've reported the problem to Google https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/TjeewtpNWf8

I found the demo app http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html worked on my device with Android 4.2.1 You might need to tweak the code slightly, however the method calls do work.

Comment: It's good to know that it's not just me.  I assume they've changed something between the two versions.

Comment: Cheers for that. The swiping problem still exists for me on KitKat, with the example on Google ui testing page. It goes into the Apps screen, tries to swipe to the left, then tries to go to the right, and then says it can't find the "Settings" app, despite the fact that on my phone the settings app is on the third page (which it never gets to).

Comment: @JulianHarty Hi Julian, Have you given up on uiautomator and moved over to Espresso?

Answer (score 0):

Hello even i faced the same issue then first i deleted the build.xml which i had and created the new build.xml file then ant build then run. it works for me try the same..